# How to move sidebar from right to left side in WooCommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar, storefront

I have one problem that dont know how to resolve myself. I have a WooCommerce site  that is using Galeria Storefront Child theme. In their setup in shop page, the sidebar can be only on right side. I want to move sidebar to the left, and ONLY on shop page. I tried this CSS:

```
div.woocommerce_product_categories-2.widget .woocommerce widget_product_categories {
    float:left!important;
}
```

but seems that dont change nothing.. Sidebar is still on left side. Help?

Comment: Can we see a live example? That bit of css doesn't really help.

Comment: Sorry. Now is live. :)

Comment: The sidebar is on the right side.

Comment: I meen on left side.. My mistake. lol

Comment: It looks like there should be a setting within WooCommerce(or the theme you are using) to change this without editing CSS, because the styling to accomplish this is already built in. If you change the body class of `right-sidebar` to `left-sidebar`, it will work as you desire. So I would look for a setting that lets you specify which layout to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce 5.2.2

```css
.with_aside .sections_group {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply left float to the sidebar and right float to the content. Also, swap the margin from left to right side, etc.

Note, you have media queries within your stylesheets so you'll have to fiddle with specificity.

```css
body.archive #primary{
  float: right;
  margin-left: 4.347826087%;
  margin-right: 0;
}
body.archive #secondary {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: How to apply this css only on shop page?

Comment: Updated my answer. Look at the classes set on `body` element and use them in `css` selectors.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change/Apply float:right to your content container
2. Change/Apply float:left to your sidebar container

You have adjust margins and paddings accordingly when sidebar shifts to left.